# How to close excel session before use

Tags: excel, vba

With my company's software I get 5 extraction (excel file), each extraction has one deicated session and the files are named Cartel1, Cartel2, Cartel3, Cartel4, Cartel5.

I can loop each session and I'm able to copy data, but I can't to close the session, after do wath I want.

my code:

```
   Sub import_Spedito()
        Dim wb As Workbook
    
        Dim xlapp As Object
        Dim rngdati As Range, valDati
        Dim i As Integer
        
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook    
        Set SheetDict = Nothing
        Set SheetDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        Set rngdati = Sheets("Parameters").Range("A1", Sheets("Parameters").Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        valDati = rngdati.Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(valDati, 1)
            SheetDict.Add valDati(i, 1), valDati(i, 2)
        Next
        
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To 5
            Set xlapp = GetObject("Cartel" & i).Application
            With xlapp
            .Sheets(1).Cells.Select
            .Selection.Copy
            End With

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                xlapp.Quit SaveChanges:=False    
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
            
            wb.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = CStr(SheetDict("Cartel" & i))
            wb.ActiveSheet.Paste
    next i 
    end sub
```

I tried also some code:

```
xlapp.close SaveChanges:=False
```

or insert the code into with like:

```
With xlapp
.close
End With
```

but nothing, I'm can't close the session.
Any suggestion will be great
Fabrizio

Hi, I solved!!
we all know that to hide the allert need to use .`DisplayAlerts = False` in my case I put this command in my code and it sure works,but on the currect session.
to close any other session the command will be add to loop code.

```
Set xlapp = GetObject("Cartel" & i).Application
With xlapp
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Sheets(1).Cells.Select
    .Selection.Copy
    .Quit
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

thank
Fabrizio

Comment: `xlapp.Quit` doesn't take any arguments

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?
The problem may be in trying to close a unsaved workbook.
Try:

```
wb.Saved = True
```

This won't actually save the workbook, but just make it look like it is saved.
And then:

```
xlapp.Quit
```